# How to play sound from a video OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video

I'm playing a mp4 file in python, but the sound of the video doesn't comes out, I searched for a while if it's anyway to play the sound, but I could not find anything. Does anyone knows how to play the sound?

I post the code that displays de video :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
 
# Check if camera opened successfully
#if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
 # print("Error opening video stream or file")
 
# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
 
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
 
    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
 
  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break
 
# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()
 
# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems useless that OpenCV doesn't allow to play the sound. I'm using Python 3 by the way. Thank you.

> **ANSWER:** OpenCV is a computer-vision library. It does not support audio. If you want to play sound, you can try [ffpyplayer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffpyplayer/). – Thanks to  >>> yushulx

Comment: OpenCV is a computer-vision library. It does not support audio. If you want to play sound, you can try [ffpyplayer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffpyplayer/).

Comment: well that makes sense, kind of odd that a video can not support audio. than you @yushulx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pyglet to play video along with its audio....
Hope this helps...

```
import pyglet
vid_path='vid1.mp4' # Name of the video
window=pyglet.window.Window()
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vid_path)

player.queue(MediaLoad)
player.play()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.get_texture().blit(50,50)


pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this no longer works. I am on to continue to find a simple way.