# Python play audio in sync with cv2 video

Tags: python, audio, opencv

I am very new to the `cv2` library, and since I recently discovered [it is unable to play audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546837/how-to-play-sound-from-a-video-cv2-in-python) I wanted to know if there is another library that will allow me to play the audio in sync with the video itself (preferably without needing an audio file, just using the video's audio)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a very simple method that I will found after researching later, unfortunately, it requires a separate audio file that matches the video:
First, import `simpleaudio` as `sa` (install it with pip if necessary) and then add this piece of code to your `cv2` video player. Add it before the while loop but after the line of code that defines the video file:

```
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("AudioFile.wav")
wave_obj.play()
```

Then you must manually adjust the waitKey until the audio matches the video, otherwise it might be too fast or too slow. Generally a value close to 25 must be used, and if the audio abruptly ends, try adding one to the value until it matches